# How to remove non alphanumeric characters in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

{...., '5':24, '/':25', 'a':26', ....}

How can I remove the punctuations and digits in order to only keep the alphanumeric characters in the dictionary?

I can do a traditional way to remove those items by indexing the key, but is there an efficient way to remove them by using regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with dictionary `d`:

```
d = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key.isalpha()}
```

Comment: Also, the digits are still being included in the dictionary

Comment: You could use a regexp instead of `isalnum`, but there's really no point.  For checking short strings like this the overhead isn't worth it and it ends up needlessly complicating the problem.

Comment: @YanLong the "numeric" in "alphanumeric" means the digits.  Use `isalpha` to keep only letters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit your dict in place and not create a new one:

```
for key in list(d):
    if not key.isalpha():
        del d[key]
```

**update**

I added the `list` for python3, so it will create a copy of the dict's keys, if you won't do that you will have `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: if you're not using the value you might as well do `for key in d:`

Comment: I had this error: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: @PatrickHaugh right, made a small update so the code will work on python3